# Magento M1 C.E to M2 C.E Data migration Installation and Configuration issues

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

We are trying to Migrate Magento 1.9.x to 2.0.x data migration using the [Magento Data Migration Tools Script](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool.html).

**Data Migration Tool**
Install Data Migration Tool - Done Without error
Upgrade Data Migration Tool - Done Without error
Configure migration - Done Without error

**Migrate using Data Migration Tool**
Run the settings migration command
 - Error and unable to proceed next steps.

> bin/magento migrate:settings [-r|--reset] {path to config.xml}

**Notice :** Trying to get property of non-object in config.php 
 
We are getting the errors in config.xml configuration. 
Anyone please review the issues screenshots and let me know your suggestions to fixes the issues.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
    <step title="Settings Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
    </step>
    <step title="Stores Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
    <step title="Data Integrity Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
    </step>
    <step title="EAV Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Log Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Ratings Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Tier Price Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="PostProcessing Step">
        <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
    </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Log Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    </steps>
    <source version="1.9.2.3">
    <database host="localhost" name="magento1924" user="magent19" password ="naedG.h~_RiO"/>
    </source>
    <destination version="2.1.6">
    <database host="localhost" name="magento20" user="magento20" password ="o)+xr3G&).4{"/>
    </destination>
    <options>
    <map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/migration/1.9.2.3/map.xml</map_file>
    <eav_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-eav.xml</eav_map_file>
    <eav_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/eav-document-groups.xml</eav_document_groups_file>
    <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>
    <log_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-log.xml</log_map_file>
    <log_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/log-document-groups.xml</log_document_groups_file>
    <settings_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
    <customer_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>
    <customer_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/customer-document-groups.xml</customer_document_groups_file>
    <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/customer-attribute-groups.xml</customer_attribute_groups_file>
    <delta_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/deltalog.xml</delta_document_groups_file>
    <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/order-grids-document-groups.xml</order_grids_document_groups_file>
    <map_document_groups>etc/ce-to-ce/map-document-groups.xml</map_document_groups>
    <class_map>etc/ce-to-ce/class-map.xml</class_map>
    <tier_price_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-tier-price.xml</tier_price_map_file>
    <!--
    In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
    -->
    <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
    <!--
    Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
    NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
    and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
     -->
    <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
    <source_prefix />
    <dest_prefix />
   <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
    <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
    <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
    <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
    <edition_migrate>ce-to-ce</edition_migrate>
    <edition_number>1.9.2.3</edition_number>
    <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
    <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;
   </init_statements_destination>
    <crypt>
    <key><![CDATA[d276c6f2aefc131816f965d40d4e02fc]]></key>
    </crypt>
    <map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.3/map.xml</map_file>
    <settings_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.3/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
    </options>
    </config>
```

Comment: It seems an error in your `config.xml`. Could you please update the question with the content of this file (no print screen please)?

Comment: @diazwatson thanks for your reply. We will remove the screenshots from our questions. You said the error in config.xml how to fix this issues ?

Comment: How can I tell you what is wrong (if any) and how to fix it if I cannot see the content of the config.xml you are using?

Comment: @diazwatson okay , can i share the config.xml here ?

Comment: You don't have to share the file, just 1. Edit your question,  2. Copy the content of the config.xml you are using and paste in there. 3. Save changes. Then me or anybody else can have a look and see if there is something wrong :)

Comment: @diazwatson,  We have updated the config.xml code , kindly review the same and let us know ur suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove version from `source` and `destination` tags:

```
<source>
    <database host="localhost" name="magento1924" user="magent19" password ="naedG.h~_RiO"/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="localhost" name="magento20" user="magento20" password ="o)+xr3G\&amp;).4{"/>
</destination>
```

Also, make sure you scape the ampersand in the password changing

```
o)+xr3G\&).4{
```

to

```
o)+xr3G\&amp;).4{
```

Then try to run the data migration tool again. It should work.

Comment: As per your suggestion we have fixed the issues and working fine .
Thanks  for your help @diazwatson.

Comment: Glad to help :)